# Getting First/Most Recent Entry in DDB using Lambda

Tags: java, database, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DynamoDb with the partition key as an ISO 8601 formatted string. I want to get the attributes of the most recently added (largest time) entry in the DDB table using a Java Lambda function.

What’s the best/fastest way to do this?

Comment: Scan the entire database. A key-value store (which dynamo is) is not designed for such a query. Alternatively set up e.g. dynamodb streams and store the information "what is the latest" specifically *somewhere*, e.g. under the key "latest" in your dynamodb.

Comment: Using a timestamp as a PK is kind of weird, in that you need to know the PK before doing a query or get, and how/why would you know the timestamp in advance?

Comment: So your formatted string looks like this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`? Then it is best practice to store the date part as PK and the Hours-Minutes-Seconds part as sort key. See [Best practices for handling time series data in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html#bp-time-series-examples)